# Linux script listing directory

Tags: linux, bash

I need a linux shell script for listing everything in a directory.
But I want to output also if it is a directory or a file

Can someone help me?

Comment: Could you explain why plain `ls` doesn't work for you?

Comment: Can someone give a script example?

Comment: This is a shell programming question, how could it off topic? Ridiculous.

Comment: It was closed for the wrong reason, but it still should have been closed -- under the `Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results` close reaosn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Can someone give a script example?`

Here is a script that lists all directories and files:

```
for i in *; do
    [[ -d "$i" ]] && echo "d-$i"
    [[ -f "$i" ]] && echo "f-$i"
    [[ -b "$i" ]] && echo "b-$i"
done
```

This is because OP wanted to do it via a script otherwise `ls -l` does the job.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ls -l`

```
$ ls -l /tmp
drwx------ 2 me me 4096 Nov 21 10:16 buu    <--- dir
-rwx------ 2 me me 4096 Nov 21 10:16 foo    <--- file
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me me    1 Nov 21 11:16 b -> a <--- link
```

The first character on the first block shows the [file type](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/ls.1.asp):

```
-    Regular file
b    Block special file
c    Character special file
d    Directory
l    Symbolic link
n    Network file
p    FIFO
s    Socket
```